# What could cause Wired ethernet adapter to remain stuck on "connecting" until I reload nmcli

Tags: debian, networking, networkmanager, nmcli, ifupdown

When I boot up my debian machine, my ethernet adapter remains in *"connecting..."* state, not actually *"connected"*, it used to always be connected by the time the machine was booted up.

If I open a terminal and run

```
sudo nmcli connection reload && nmcli networking off && nmcli networking on
```

The ethernet connects instantly and I get internet.

What could cause this behavior?